# How to easily authenticate fingerprint?

Tags: android, xamarin, fingerprint

While I am relatively new to Xamarin, I have spent hours on end trying to figure out how to get android fingerprint authentication to work on my mobile app. My objective is to simply check if the fingerprint is correct on my S7 and then move me to the next activity, however, all the solutions I have found uses FingerprintManagerCompat, which I can not find for the life of me. Is FingerprintManagerCompat retired or am I doing something wrong?